# NSOutlineView drag promises with directories

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview, nspasteboard

How does one implement an `NSOutlineViewDataSource` to allow dragging directories that do not exist in the file system at the time of dragging to the Finder? I have searched and searched and read a ton of the documentation, but have had great difficulty finding anything of value that works. I use a custom data source that manages a file system-like tree, and all the items are instances of a class that keeps track of its path. I would like to be able to drag files and directories out of the outline view into the Finder.

I have:

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView 
         writeItems:(NSArray *)items 
       toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard 
{
    NSMutableArray *types = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (JOItemInfo *itemInfo in items) {
        NSString *extension = itemInfo.name.pathExtension;
        if (extension.length > 0) [types addObject:extension];
    }

    [pasteboard declareTypes:@[(__bridge_transfer NSString *)kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise] 
                       owner:self];
    [pasteboard setPropertyList:types 
                        forType:(__bridge_transfer NSString *)kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise];
    DDLogInfo(@"Wrote types %@ to pasteboard %@ for key %@", 
               types, 
               pasteboard, 
               (__bridge_transfer NSString *)kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise);
    return YES;
}
```

and an implementation of `-outlineView:namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:forDraggedItems:` that writes the items inside of the given path. This works in that I can drag items out to the Finder, but when I let go nothing else happens, and the `-...namesOfPromisedFilesDropped...` method isn't even called. Also,

```
[self.outlineView setDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle:NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleRegular];
[self.outlineView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationNone forLocal:YES];
[self.outlineView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationCopy forLocal:NO];
```

is in my `-awakeFromNib`. The `if (extension.length > 0) ...` was based on an example I found somewhere, but it was dated, and the documentation says to return an extension, so I think that is appropriate. Personally, I find the documentation for this whole area very lacking, especially in regard to an `NSOutlineView`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed `(__bridge_transfer NSString *)kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise` to `NSFilesPromisePboardType`, and I can now drag files (with an extension at least) and they can be dropped successfully in the Finder. (I had used the former b/c the documentation for the latter recommended that, but they do not have the same effect.)

Also, I tried removing the conditional and allowing it to add an empty string for an empty extension, which worked like a charm. I can now drag out of the outline view into the Finder.